# white screen of death with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, debugging, wsod

I have move a codeigniter script from a development server to production server (

> same server, just different domains, so no PHP/database/apache config/ or related issues

)

I have been able to get log in just one place /application/logs folder
I have tried everything else for logs ( enabled php logs etc etc.)
nothing seems to show me what is the issue, what's causing white screen)

```
DEBUG - 2016-06-16 15:47:48 --> Config Class Initialized

DEBUG - 2016-06-16 15:47:48 --> Hooks Class Initialized

DEBUG - 2016-06-16 15:47:48 --> Utf8 Class Initialized

DEBUG - 2016-06-16 15:47:48 --> UTF-8 Support Enabled

DEBUG - 2016-06-16 15:47:49 --> URI Class Initialized

DEBUG - 2016-06-16 15:47:49 --> Router Class Initialized

DEBUG - 2016-06-16 15:47:49 --> No URI present. Default controller set.

DEBUG - 2016-06-16 15:47:49 --> Output Class Initialized

DEBUG - 2016-06-16 15:47:49 --> Security Class Initialized

DEBUG - 2016-06-16 15:47:49 --> Input Class Initialized

DEBUG - 2016-06-16 15:47:49 --> Global POST and COOKIE data sanitized

DEBUG - 2016-06-16 15:47:49 --> Language Class Initialized

DEBUG - 2016-06-16 15:47:49 --> Loader Class Initialized

DEBUG - 2016-06-16 15:47:49 --> Helper loaded: url_helper

DEBUG - 2016-06-16 15:47:49 --> Helper loaded: file_helper

DEBUG - 2016-06-16 15:47:49 --> Database Driver Class Initialized

DEBUG - 2016-06-16 15:47:49 --> Session Class Initialized
```

If anyone has any idea, please let me know
so far I have

Added development server in `index.php`
Googled, and tried everything else for some error to show up, nothing worked till now.

I am kinda out of ideas for now.

Got some entries in server now, but they appear to be more of hack attempts than actual errors.

2016-06-17 03:05:04.050 [INFO] [124.253.119.242:14578] File not found [/home/miverali/public_html/domain.com/404.shtml]

2016-06-17 03:05:04.050 [INFO] [124.253.119.242:14578] File not found [/home/miverali/public_html/domain.com/application/index.php]

2016-06-17 02:59:32.621 [INFO] [178.63.13.15:27365] File not found [/home/miverali/public_html/domain.com/404.shtml]

2016-06-17 02:59:32.621 [INFO] [178.63.13.15:27365] File not found [/home/miverali/public_html/domain.com/robots.txt]

2016-06-17 02:55:47.575 [INFO] [5.9.73.227:50935] File not found [/home/miverali/public_html/domain.com/404.shtml]

2016-06-17 02:55:47.575 [INFO] [5.9.73.227:50935] File not found [/home/miverali/public_html/domain.com/robots.txt]

Comment: Sounds like you've checked PHP error logs - which is good. Did you check Apache's/Nginx's error log? What HTTP status code is the white screen of death?

Comment: there is nothing on that error log.

Answer (score 1):

I have face this issue because of the DB Driver is not responding.

go to `application/config/database.php`

---

If **codeigniter 3.0-** ( less than 3.0)

```
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = ''; # Change to mysqli
```

If **codeigniter 3.0+** ( greater than 3.0)

```
'dbdriver' => '', #  Change to mysqli
```

Comment: Sorry , didnt' work, changing has no  effect on it. however, it appears that some of your have been trying to help me somehow , ( because i am getting different entries in database now.DEBUG - 2016-06-17 10:06:33 --> Config Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2016-06-17 10:06:33 --> Hooks Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2016-06-17 10:06:33 --> Utf8 Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2016-06-17 10:06:33 --> UTF-8 Support Enabled
DEBUG - 2016-06-17 10:06:33 --> URI Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2016-06-17 10:06:33 --> Router Class Initialized
ERROR - 2016-06-17 10:06:33 --> 404 Page Not Found --> page

Comment: @competent123 what's going on server ??

Comment: sorry, i didnt' understand what do you mean by whats going on server? nobody else has access to server, but it appears some one you have been trying to help with some special urls or something like that. also, like i have updated my question to make it a bit more clear, the hosting and development servers are the same, only change is the domain name

Comment: @competent123 where does this debug prints from ??

Comment: This is from /application/logs folder Config Class Initialized
Hooks Class Initialized
 Utf8 Class Initialized
 UTF-8 Support Enabled
 URI Class Initialized
 Router Class Initialized
 No URI present. Default controller set.
 Output Class Initialized
 Security Class Initialized
 Input Class Initialized
Global POST and COOKIE data sanitized
Language Class Initialized
Loader Class Initialized
Helper loaded: url_helper
Helper loaded: file_helper
Database Driver Class Initialized
Session Class Initialized  Can provide cpanel access if you are willing to take a look @abdulla

Answer (score 0):

Thought I'd reply to this as it came up top in the searches when I was looking for an answer...

I found the answer by looking in the console on Chrome when I got a white screen. There was just this error:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED
```

The solution was to go to the config file (`/application/config/config.php`) and find `$config['compress_output']`. In my case this was set to TRUE - change to FALSE and you might be good to go...